# nohup:ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'

Tags: php, linux, centos, centos6, centos5

I want to start my server through nohup.php but the command is not running and displays following error

> nohup:ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'

I am using ssh through putty, this is what i am doing

> nohup php server1.php

Answer (score 95, accepted):

That's not an error - it's normal behavior. It just informs you that once started the in/output is removed from your console.

To avoid the message you need to start it like

```
nohup php server1.php </dev/null &>/dev/null &
```

Comment: Also see [Difference between 2>&-, 2>/dev/null, |&, &>/dev/null and >/dev/null 2>&1](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/70963) on Unix and Linux stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the output of the executed command,You need to follow this step,
execute the command $tailf nohup.out

Please note : Nohup command creates a file with name nohup.out in same location where you have executed the nohup command .

Comment: is `tail` instead of `tailf`.

Comment: tailf will print out the last 10 lines of the given file and then wait for this file to grow
We can use tail -<no_of_lines>f command to show  no_of_lines of the given file and then wait for this file to grow
Read more at: https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/tailf.1.html

Comment: It turns out that there is really a `tailf` command, but my knowledge is too little, thank you for adding it!

Comment: use tail -100f <file_name > , it will work for you .