# Laravel queues run forever

Tags: laravel-4

I have a page which supports some kind of mail notificiation. When user inserts some data, I want to send mail to another. I know, `Mail::send()` works perfectly, but it is slow. So I want to push this mail to queue. I use iron.io as provider. Everything works perfectly until I close console.

So is it possible to run `php artisan queue:listen` forever after I close console on Win and Linux?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can run every process in the background in linux by using `nohup`

```
nohup php artisan queue:listen
```

This will keep the process running even if you close your terminal, nohup will force to ignore hangup signals.

nohup creates a logfile. If you want to suppress this, you can add

```
 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

after your command

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot, also with this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646320/nohupignoring-input-and-appending-output-to-nohup-out-in-linux-centos

Comment: Consider monitoring this with something like `supervisord` too.

Comment: You're welcome! You can ignore what nohup is telling you and close everything. You could build some kind of checkup if the process is still running, though it's quite reliable

Comment: I do not have root user of cmd, so when I set `nohup` command and then close the terminal, the queue stops. The command or process is not running in background as expected. My question is, using non root user could be the issue here?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Feel free to ask a new question and make sure to include all the information about what you are doing so that people can help you